# Customize FullAjaxExceptionHandler to show only a faces message for specific exceptions

Tags: ajax, jsf, exception, omnifaces

I am working on JSF application which uses omnifaces. I have a custom exception handler class for all ajax requests by extending the FullAjaxExceptionHandler and overriding the shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(). In here i add my business errors in to the context and i have to display these messages in the xhtml pages. the ajax calls are made from client using p:commandButton. 
But the values that i set in the context from my custom exception handler are not being displayed on the xhtml page.

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler {

@Override
protected boolean shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(FacesContext context, Throwable exception) {

context.addMessage(null, FacesMessage);
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, null);
context.getPartialViewContext().setRenderAll(true);
context.renderResponse();
setRequest(request, baseRunTimeException);
return false;
}
}
```

But the message that i add in the context are not being displayed in the p:messages tag

Please let me know if there anything wrong with this approach ?

Comment: You're basically disabling the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` and fully taking over its job by attempting to manually handle navigation and rendering in a poor way. You're not utilizing the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` in a sensible way. That method is intented to return true/false on a specific exception type and nothing more. What exactly do you want? Just adding the exception as a faces message? If so, use OmniFaces `FacesMessageExceptionHandler` instead.

Comment: Hi I checked the FacesMessageExceptionHandler, but mysceanrio is a little different, i dont want to display all the Exceptions as Messages, some of them i will redirect to another error page. Will it be possible to do it achieve this functionality? If so Please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per the functional requirement in your comment,

> *i dont want to display all the Exceptions as Messages, some of them i will redirect to another error page.*

On those which you'd like to forward (not redirect) to error page, just let `shouldHandleExceptionRootCause()` method return `true` and register those error pages in `web.xml` the usual way.

On those which you'd like to show as faces message, just add the desired faces message and then return `false`.

The below example assumes that you'd like to show the message of an exemplary custom `com.example.SystemException` as a faces message.

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(FacesContext context, Throwable exception) {
    if (exception instanceof SystemException) {
        Messages.addGlobalError(exception.getMessage());
        return false; // Don't show error page, just stay in same page.
    }

    return true; // Show error page as usual for other exceptions.
}
```

Comment: The problem with shouldHandleExceptionRootCause, is that there is no way to remove the Exception from the queue, and because of that it messes up – since exception is still sitting in the event queue.

Comment: The problem with shouldHandleExceptionRootCause, is that there is no way to remove the Exception from the queue, and because of that it messes up – since exception is still sitting in the event queue.  

So we found a work around like override the handle() also
@Override
public void handle() throws FacesException {
.
.
.
if (!shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(context, exception)) {
 unhandledExceptionQueuedEvents.remove();
 getWrapped().handle();
 return;
}
}
And i did whatever you had mentioned in the shouldHandleExceptionRootCause()

Comment: I can see where you're getting at. As per [this commit](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/fa74dcd67d30fb80539746a0445347c1a1a2e5bb) the removal of the exception is now done before the `shouldHandleExceptionRootCause()` method. It's available in today's [2.3-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.3-SNAPSHOT/). Can you give it a try?

Comment: We tested it with the SNAPSHOT it solved our issue.  Now i can achieve the desired functionality just by overriding the shouldHandleExceptionRootCause() .